# One of the logic conditions failing to work properly

Tags: c#

I can't seem to figure out why this bit of code is failing, it seems simple enough.

**Code:**

```
string[] ignore = File.ReadAllLines(@"logicfiles\[flag]-[ignore-these-links].txt");

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(rawHtml);

foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    string linkUrl = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
    if (!ignore.Any(linkUrl.Contains) && linkUrl.Length < 10 && !linkUrl.StartsWith("/"))
    {
        DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Add(linkUrl, keywordUsed, "", "", engineUsed);
    }
}
```

The above code does not work as in it just adds every URL to the `DataGrid` this part `!ignore.Any(linkUrl.Contains)` is the part that is failing to work right, the `ignore` array contains strings like `facebook`, `youtube` etc if the url `linkUrl` does NOT contain one of these strings in it, then add it to the `DataGrid` (is how it should work)

But if i do this:

```
string[] ignore = File.ReadAllLines(@"logicfiles\[flag]-[ignore-these-links].txt");

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(rawHtml);

foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    string linkUrl = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
    if (linkUrl.Length < 10 && !linkUrl.StartsWith("/"))
    {
        DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Add(linkUrl, keywordUsed, "", "", engineUsed);
    }
}
```

And take that part of the code away, the other 2 conditions work perfectly, so I know the part of the logic not working is `!ignore.Any(linkUrl.Contains)`

I cannot see why, if someone could point out the issue it would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah sorry Joel i did not even see it.

Comment: differences in case (upper / lower)? Are you sure the values in the array are exactly contained in the `linkUrls`? Instead of passing in values from the text file, try passing your own list of values and testing with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Contains` logic is fine. There may be something wrong with the values that are being passed in from the text file. An upper / lower case issue or similar.

I recommend printing out or otherwise inspecting both the parsed url values, and the filter strings coming in from the text file and ensuring you're comparing what you think you are.

Here is just the logic for the `Contains` with a set of values showing it working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var linkUrls = new List<string>{
            "https://youtube.com/2134",
            "https://google.com/2134",
            "https://microsoft.com/2134"
        };
        
        var ignores = new List<string>{
            "youtube",
            "somethingElse"
        };
        
        foreach (var linkUrl in linkUrls)
        {
            if (!ignores.Any(linkUrl.Contains))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"passed filter: {linkUrl}");
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Output:

> passed filter: https://google.com/2134

> passed filter: https://microsoft.com/2134

See:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/8wud9O

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you for the help :) I took away the other 2 conditions (like you have above) and it works, it seems It does not like me doing: ```if (!ignore.Any(linkUrl.Contains) && linkUrl.Length < 10 && !linkUrl.StartsWith("/"))``` all 3 together, I shall debug more, thanks again.